# Is there some tricks to better index a URL column in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, index, index-tuning

I'm working with a table that needs fast retrieve rows by its `url` column. But they all will be starting with `http://www.`:

```
http://www.google.com
http://www.amazon.com
http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

I was thinking if indexing urls this way would not degree performance for b-tree index. Then I raised some options but not sure if will make some improvement:

- Add another column removing `http://www.` to apply index
- Add another column with some hash function like `md5(url)` to apply index

Does this will have some gain on performance?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are ulrs that start with `https://` And not all have `www.`, this one for example: `http://dba.stackexchange.com/...`

Comment: Yes, in this case I would store `http://dba.stackexchange.com/` in the url column and `dba.stackexchange.com` in another column to index

Comment: You can also try function based index , Postgres seems to support it: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-expressional.html

Comment: I'd write a `simplify_url` function, then use it in my queries and create an expression index on it.